# How to get full url along with # symbol in php

Tags: php, angularjs, url, angularjs-routing

I am using AngularJS routing with php,
so that my urls look like

```
http://localhost/admin/home#/categories
```

When ever I am trying to get url it wont gave full url. It gives only `/admin/home`.

I am using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and codeigniter segment. Both are not working.

Can  any one help?

Comment: without removing # from url you will not get full url in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Answer (score 1):

This information is not being past to the server I'm afraid. 
The url part after # is only for browser use. You can add GET or POST parameters to pass this information to your server like:

http://localhost/admin/home?hash=categories#/categories

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]
```

It will give the full url, including everything.

If you want to strip stuff from the url, use things like this:

```
$url = trim(strtok("$url", '?'));
$url = str_replace("#!/", "", "$url");
```